# Is there a way to create a new database in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a new database from within Wordpress.  I don't know if this is possible, and if so, how would you do it?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. While it's trivial to send the appropriate query to mySQL, a sizeable portion of Wordpress installations is going to be configured in a away that prohibits the mySQL user from creating a new database. Why do you think you need this? What's wrong with sharing the main Wordpress DB?

Comment: It's difficult to explain why.  Suffice to say that it's a project that has a larger scope than wordpress and wordpress will be used as the interface for parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need a new database (unlikely but that's not the point of your question) then the user that WordPress is running with needs to have the ability to create databases. As Pekka indicates, most installations will not allow this.

If your design will allow, try including your own naming convention in your tables. I've done this a few times to ensure separation of data (when browsing the database) and for a few other reasons.

example:

```
$fullTablename = $wpdb->prefix . $pluginPrefix . $table;
```